# can we add the common data to the existing sharepoint list at once using infopath forms 2010

Tags: list, list-view

I have an Employee Trainings list which I need to update a Training which is common to all the employees. This training should be added to all the employees.

Training list contains :

- Employee Full name
- Emp number
- First name
- Last name
- Training Topic
- Trg start date
- Trg hrs and comments.

I have created a infopath form to add and update the training for each employee.
But there is no provision in this form to add a training which is common to all employees at once.
Can we create the form and update the sharepoint list as per the above requirement?